# Command without sudo works but requires sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, sudo

I have already solved this problem but I do not know why this solves the problem and I don't like not knowing what went wrong. I'm using the terminal on Ubuntu

Here was the issue...

1. If I run `$ ngm -args` it runs but fails because it requires sudo
2. If I run `$ sudo ngm -args` I get the error like ngm not found
3. If I run `$ sudo /usr/local/lib/ngm -args` it runs with sudo and works perfectly.

I don't understand why the 3 works and 2 doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to run `$ ngm -args`, the shell will look for the executable in it's `$PATH` variable, and it finds it. When trying to run the executable it finds that it has to be `sudo` and exits.
When you run `$ sudo ngm -args`, the shell will look for the executable in the `$PATH` environment of the Root user, and it can't find it.
When running it like the last option, the shell doesn't need to look in the `$PATH` of the root user, because it finds it in the path that you specified `/usr/local/lib/ngm`, so both issues are gone.

[This might be a starting point in order to understand the PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))